# Don't understand SwiftUI Text layout

Tags: swiftui, rendering, word-wrap

I want to output some text on all 4 sides of the view.  This is my code:

```
   var body: some View {
        Spacer()
        Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH")
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
            Spacer()
            Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
        }.frame(height: 200)
        Spacer()
        Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH")
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

and this is the output:
[image]

Questions:

- Why is the text left wrapped, but the same text right not? And how can I avoid wrapping?
- Why has the text left a different margin than the text right? And how can I make them equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe part of the problem is that you're not forcing both to be centered, also one is drawn, in it's layout priority before the other. So If you set their frame widths, to their maximum, each would take 1/2 the view. Notice the rotationEffect doesn't actually adjust the `frame` rotation.

[image]

Getting your frames to constantly match is the only "True" way to resolve this issue, or to use other formatting tricks such as `.minimumFontScale(..)` or even `.lineLimit(..)`.

#### Example

```
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            Spacer()
            Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }.frame(height: 200)
        Spacer()
        Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        Spacer()
    }
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

In this example I can get an expected output for various dynamic types like so.

[image]

Comment: Great! One more thing: How can I avoid text wrapping on the rotated texts?

Comment: I found the reason for the text wrapping, and how to avoid it. Pls see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[xTwisteDx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76930445/1987726) is great (+1, accepted). I modified it a little to avoid text wrapping of the rotated texts.

They were wrapped, because text rotation happens after the text has been laid out. This can be seen when the rotation modifiers are out commented. Then, both texts simply don't fit on one line.

To get unwrapped rotated texts, I put them in a `ZStack`, one text adjusted left and the other right, using `Spacers`. This way both unrotated texts can use the whole screen width and are not wrapped.

After rotation, everything looks right.
Here is the code:

```
Spacer()
Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
Spacer()
ZStack {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH")
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
        Spacer()
    }
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        Spacer()
    Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH")
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
    }
}.frame(height: 200)
Spacer()
Text("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
Spacer()
```

[image]